# Getting access to the index in plain JS

Tags: javascript, indexing, rails-api

so I'm building a seemingly simple playlist JS app with a rails backend and I'm running into an issue. I cannot seem to get the return value I want. I have my tracks and playlist rendered but I need to get the index of each song on the page and I am only able to figure out how to get the first track. I'm new to JS as you can probably tell so any advise you have would be great. Thanks in advance.

````
    function getPlaylists() {
  fetch(BACKEND_URL)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(list  => {
       list.data.map((playlist, index)  =>  {      
          let newPlaylist = new Playlist(playlist, playlist.attributes) ;       
          
         document.getElementById('playlist-container').innerHTML += newPlaylist.renderPlaylistCard();         
        })       
        }
  )
}

function postFetch(title, artist){
    fetch(BACKEND_URL, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
      body: JSON.stringify({
        name: name,
        title: title, 
        artist: artist
      })      
    })    
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(playlist => {          
      const playlistData = playlist.data;      
      let newPlaylist = new Playlist(playlistData, playlistData.attributes);
    
      document.getElementById('playlist-container').innerHTML += newPlaylist.renderPlaylistCard() ;
   
    })  
  }
```class Playlist {
 
  constructor(playlist, playlistAttributes) {    

     this.id = playlist.id
     this.name = playlistAttributes.name  
     this.track = playlistAttributes.tracks
     Playlist.all.push(this);  
 //debugger
}

renderPlaylistCard() {
  return   `            
   <div data-id=${this.id}>
   <h3><li>Playlist Name: ${this.name}</h3></li> 
   <h3><li>Title: ${this.track[0].title}</h3></li> 
   <h3><li>Title: ${this.track[0].artist}</h3></li> 
   <button data-id=${this.id}>EDIT!</button>    
   </div> </li>
   ` ;  
    }
    }  

    Playlist.all = [];
````

Comment: Don't use `map()` if the function doesn't return anything and you're not using the return value. Use `forEach()` instead.

Comment: Hey @Barmar thanks for the reply. I have changed it to forEach. I'm still getting the same result though. do you see anything else that could be causing an issue or have any other suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: My comment had nothing to do with the issue, and I don't really understand the question.

Comment: What index are you talking about, and what do you want to do with it?

Comment: Are you talking about the index in `(playlist, index)`?

Comment: oh, sorry. Each playlist has multiple tracks but I'm only seeing the first track. I'm trying to list each track under the playlist that it belongs to.

Comment: Sounds like you may need a nested loop that iterates over the tracks.

Comment: cool, I'll give that a shot, thanks!